# Find Diff between two lists of different types

Tags: c#, .net, performance, compare

I want to get the difference between two large array of different types in `C#`. Performance and optimization is an important point because I have to compare large arrays of elements.

I must be able to get the missing elements from one list in relation to the other and the elements that are present but different.

The goal is to synchronize data on my database from external data provided by an `REST API`. I use `EF Core` on my server, which provides me a `TLocal[]` and the `REST API` provides me a `TRemote[]`. Since this is a large data that is retrieved from API at regular intervals, I would like to avoid transforming `TRemote` into `TLocal` to compare the two lists. I have an `ID property` common to both types that allows comparison.

Some considered possibilities:

- `HashSet`: Both list must be in the same type to use `Except/Intersect`. I'd like to keep two different types.
- `Join-Linq`: This allows to use two lists of different types but with a performance cost. In addition, I have to execute two Join to get the difference between the two lists (added/removed).
- `IEqualityComparer`: Use `Except/Intercept` with custom `EqualityComparer` to compare two objects.

Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: How do you determine whether two objects are the "same" / are "different"? Is it *just* that the IDs are the same?

Comment: Yes, an ID property is common to bot types. This determines whether it should be added/deleted/updated. To know if it necessary to update, it is necessary to compare values of both types. I think they are two different operations, one to compare lists and one to compare objects.

Comment: Yes, I would start off comparing the IDs. Once you've found a set of objects which need to be compared to see if there are updated, start comparing the objects directly.

Comment: Beyond comparing ID and to avoid transforming one type to another, consider adapting one type (or both) into another.  The adapter would be a lightweight wrapper around `TLocal` and/or `TRemote`, where the adapter delegates to the wrapped type.

Comment: You listed all possibilities and they are all about the same. They are all using a Hashset with an IEqualityComparer, also the Join does. To Execute it as SQL directly on the database, the Join is the best and only option.
If you talk about in memory, convert one of your lists to a Dictionary based on your ID, iterate over the other collections and search for each item-ID in the dictionary. A Dictionary is just a HashSet again, it just links an complete item, to your ID.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid LINQ if you seek performance (read [this](https://jackmott.github.io/programming/2016/07/22/making-obvious-fast.html)).

I would advise to keep a `Dictionary<(type of id), TLocal>` of your local data in order to efficiently [O(1)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/264766/efficiency-of-c-dictionaries) determine if a remote object needs to be inserted or updated.